# Reading CSV with Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark

I am reading a CSV file in Spark DataFrame using the code below, but the output is a mess:

```
df = spark.read.format('csv').options(header=True, inferSchema=True).csv('spark.csv')
```

Output:

> +----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------+---------------+
> |           PARID|PROPERTYHOUSENUM|PROPERTYFRACTION|PROPERTYADDRESSDIR|PROPERTYADDRESSSTREET|PROPERTYADDRESSSUF|PROPERTYADDRESSUNITDESC|PROPERTYUNITNO|PROPERTYCITY|PROPERTYSTATE|PROPERTYZIP|SCHOOLCODE|      SCHOOLDESC|MUNICODE|            MUNIDESC|RECORDDATE|  SALEDATE| PRICE|DEEDBOOK|DEEDPAGE|SALECODE|            SALEDESC|INSTRTYP|   INSTRTYPDESC|
> +----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------+---------------+
> |1075F00108000000|            4720|                |              null|            HIGHPOINT|                DR|                   null|          null|    GIBSONIA|           PA|      15044|        20|Hampton Township|     914|           Hampton  |2012-09-27|2012-09-27|120000|   15020|     356|       3|LOVE AND AFFECTIO...|      DE|           DEED|
> |0011A00237000000|               0|                |              null|              LOMBARD|                ST|                   null|          null|  PITTSBURGH|           PA|      15219|        47|      Pittsburgh|     103|3rd Ward - PITTSB...|2015-01-06|2015-01-06|  1783|    TR15|   00002|       2| CITY TREASURER SALE|      TS| TREASURER DEED|
> |0011J00047000000|            1903|                |              null|               FORBES|               AVE|                   null|          null|  PITTSBURGH|           PA|      15219|        47|      Pittsburgh|     101|1st Ward  - PITTS...|2012-10-26|2012-10-26|  4643|    TR13|     003|       2| CITY TREASURER SALE|      TS| TREASURER DEED|
> |0113B00029000000|             479|                |              null|            ROOSEVELT|               AVE|                   null|          null|  PITTSBURGH|           PA|      15202|        29|       Northgate|     803|          Bellevue  |2017-03-27|2017-03-06|     0|   16739|     166|       3|LOVE AND AFFECTIO...|      CO|CORRECTIVE DEED|
> |0119S00024000000|            5418|                |              null|             CARNEGIE|                ST|                   null|          null|  PITTSBURGH|           PA|      15201|        47|      Pittsburgh|     110|10th Ward - PITTS...|2015-02-04|2015-02-04| 27541|    TR15|   00059|      GV|     GOVERNMENT SALE|      TS| TREASURER DEED|
> +----------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------+-----------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------+----------+----------------+--------+--------------------+----------+----------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------------------+--------+---------------+
> only showing top 5 rows

I am new to big data problems and I am trying to learn how to properly use Spark for this aim. How can I read properly this dataframe? Are there some options I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You have read the dataframe correctly, but your dataframe is so wide (has too many columns) that it cannot fit in your window, so the lines are wrapped and result in a messy output.

If you want a neater output, try `df.show(vertical=True)`, or select a few columns to show, such as `df.select(df.columns[:2]).show()`, which shows the first three columns.

Comment: Is there an option to display all the columns (or some of them with some truncation) with a slider (just like for Pandas DataFrames) in order to avoid overlapping?

Comment: @Matteo unfortunately I'm not aware of any, but if you want to use a pandas dataframe, you can do `df.toPandas()` (beware that you should only do this for small spark dataframes)